# Issue combining columns in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
Obj         BIT  BIT  BIT  GAS  GAS  GAS  OIL  OIL  OIL
Date                                                   
2007-01-03   18    7    0  184   35    2   52   14    0
2007-01-09   43    3    0  249   35    2   68   11    1
2007-01-16   60    6    0  254   35    5   72   13    1
2007-01-23   69   11    1  255   43    2   81    6    0
2007-01-30   74    8    0  263   29    4   69    9    0
2007-02-06   78    6    1  259   34    2   79    6    0
2007-02-14   76    9    1  263   24    2   70   10    1
2007-02-20   85    7    0  241   20    6   72    4    0
2007-02-27   79    6    0  242   35    3   68    7    0
2007-03-06   68   14    0  225   26    2   57   10    1
```

How can I sum each of the 9 columns into 3 columns. "BIT","GAS" and "OIL"

This is the code for the dataframe which basically just gets me a cross section from a larger df I want:

```
 ABrigsA = ndfAB.xs(['BIT','GAS','OIL'],axis=1)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What "merge" operation do you want performed?  Sum?

Comment: Yes sorry, sum the values for each unique column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to sum similarly-named columns, you can use `groupby` [[tutorial docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)]:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0, axis='columns').sum()
Obj         BIT  GAS  OIL
Date                     
2007-01-03   25  221   66
2007-01-09   46  286   80
2007-01-16   66  294   86
2007-01-23   81  300   87
2007-01-30   82  296   78
2007-02-06   85  295   85
2007-02-14   86  289   81
2007-02-20   92  267   76
2007-02-27   85  280   75
2007-03-06   82  253   68
```

Comment: Sweet that worked, thanks. Just wondering, what does the level=0 do exactly? and is the axis='columns'a pre-set definition in axis that groups by the same columns?